# How to get iphone device screenshot when image animation is run on main thread?

Tags: iphone

I am perfoming image sequences animation is on main thread.
At the same time i want to take snapshot of device screen in back ground.
And by using that snapshots i want make video..

Thanks,
Keyur Prajapati

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For taking the screenshots while running the image animations

use

`[self.view.layer.presentationLayer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

instead of

`[self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];`

it will take screenshots while runing animations

iOS uses Core Animation as the rendering system. Each UIView is backed by a CALayer. Each visible layer tree is backed by a presentation tree. The layer tree contains the object model values for each layer, i.e., values you set when you assign a value to a layer property (A and B). The presentation tree contains the values that are currently being presented to the user as an animation takes place (interpolated values between A and B).

Answer (score 1):

If you're doing it in CoreAnimation you can render the layer contents into a bitmap using `-renderInContext:`. Have a look at Matt Longs [Tutorial](http://www.cimgf.com/2009/02/03/record-your-core-animation-animation/). It's for Objective-C on the Mac, but it can be easily converted for use on the iPhone.

Answer (score 1):

Create one another thread where you can do this:

```
    //Create rect portion for image if full screen then 320X480
    CGRect contextRect  = CGRectMake(0, 0, 320, 480);

  // this is whate you need
    UIGraphicsBeginImageContext(contextRect.size);  

    [self.view.layer renderInContext:UIGraphicsGetCurrentContext()];

  UIImage* viewImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();

  UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
```

***viewImage*** is the image which you needed.

You can write this code in function which can be called timely bases like per 5 seconds or according to your requirements.

Hope this is what you needed.

Comment: Thanks. i have already make it by this way.but i can't got images in proper sequence . means i missed some image during images taking time.